Angular17.How to store images in a service
in fact my problem is to find how to sort by increasing price and by decreasing price a catalog of products sold
. I have already created a pipe which allows me to sort the objects but the problem is that in my app.component.ts I cannot import my images for example like this "product={price:100,name:asterix ,image:..assets/image/asterix.png".so I was told that it is necessary to change the method and use services to store data
I haven't done anything yet because I tried to find solutions but there was no explanation or documentation that shows how images are stored in service
